# CSS positioning issue

Tags: css

I'm currently working on this [page](http://allfashionsunglasses.com/) and as it loads initially, the slideshow thumbnails will be where they're supposed to be but drops second later. I've tried changing the CSS from

```
.pika-thumbs {
    width: 995px;
    margin-left: 55px;
}
```

To

```
.pika-thumbs {
    width: 995px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    Z-index: 999;
}
```

and it stayed exactly where I wanted it to stay but the space stays and goes away when I remove the whole like of CSS.

Comment: P.S. use some editor with autosuggest to avoid typo like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot your semi-colon after `relative`:

```
.pika-thumbs {
    width: 995px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Edit:**

> and it stayed exactly where I wanted it to stay but the space stays
>   and goes away when I remove the whole like of CSS.

This is the reality of using `position: relative` and top with negative values.  Try `margin-top: -150px;` instead of `top`.

Comment: That was a typo made while I was typing here.

Answer (score 2):

position, not positioning:

```
.pika-thumbs {
    width: 995px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Good catch I didn't notice that, just the ;

Comment: That was a typo made while I was typing here